# How to make a Chrome Extension to redirect when specific pages are accessed in Manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that redirects to a pre defined page when a specified page is loaded.
I'm using webRequest for this, But now that I have to migrate to Manifest V3, webRequest can not be used anymore.
Can anyone help me with rewrite the script to make it work with Manifest V3?

Here's the script that I use to redirect pages:

```
var host = "http://example.com";
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
         return {redirectUrl: host + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1]};
    },
    {
        urls: [
            "*://foo.com/demo*",
            "*://www.foo.com/test/*"
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: Use [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) with regexFilter + regexSubstitution.

Comment: I did, I'm only able to block the page but not redirect. Can you give me an example script that can be used with declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess ?

Comment: There are many examples for the same in the documentation.

Comment: I do not see one for redirect tho. Can you point it out or put it here as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend using [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) for this task, it is very limited in its capabilities and has an awkward interface.

It sounds like you want to redirect the user **prior** to the page being loaded. If that's the case, you need to hook into the request/response lifecycle using [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger) API. I describe how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066060/chrome-extension-mv3-catch-zip-files-on-anchor-click)- his application seems easily adaptable to your own. This is the only way to get the same caliber request manipulation capabilities in MV3 as in MV2.

Alternative approach:
-Use the [chrome.webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/) API. This will just entail setting up event listeners/handlers for one or more of the following:

```
onBeforeNavigate -> onCommitted -> [onDOMContentLoaded] -> onCompleted
```

[Here](https://grep.app/search?q=chrome.webNavigation) you can find many examples of other projects using this API.