# Chrome extension mv3 - catch zip files on anchor click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I put two pieces of code.
The first contains the chrome extension manifest version 2 files.
Here if I click on anchor with href pointed to zip file, then extension redirect to page from extension.
This is a worked example.

I am trying to achieve this for chrome extension with manifest version 3.
This is a second pieces of code.

***First part.***
***Extension manifest version 2***

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test app mv2",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "test mv2",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "icons": {
    "128": "128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],  
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "web/main.html"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
function getHeaderFromHeaders(headers, headerName) {
  for (var i=0; i<headers.length; ++i) {
    var header = headers[i];
    if (header.name.toLowerCase() === headerName) {
      return header;
    }
  }
}

function isAllowed(details) {
  var header = getHeaderFromHeaders(details.responseHeaders, 'content-type');
  
  if (header) {
    var headerValue = header.value.toLowerCase().split(';',1)[0].trim();

    var mimeTypes = [
      'application/zip'
    ];
    
    return (mimeTypes.indexOf(headerValue) !== -1);
  }
}

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method !== 'GET') {
      // Don't intercept POST requests until http://crbug.com/104058 is fixed.
      return;
    }
    
    if (!isAllowed(details)) {
      return;
    }

    return { redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('web/main.html') };
  },
  {
    urls: [
      '<all_urls>'
    ],
    types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame']
  },
  ['blocking','responseHeaders']
 );
```

[***Full source for mv2***](https://bitbucket.org/jan_popov/mv2/src/master/)

***Second part.
Extension manifest version 3***

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test app mv3",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "./background.js"
  },
  "action": {    
    "default_title": "SW3"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"
  ],  
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": ["web/main.html"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
function getHeaderFromHeaders(headers, headerName) {
  for (var i=0; i<headers.length; ++i) {
    var header = headers[i];
    if (header.name.toLowerCase() === headerName) {
      return header;
    }
  }
}

function isAllowed(details) {
  var header = getHeaderFromHeaders(details.responseHeaders, 'content-type');
  
  if (header) {
    var headerValue = header.value.toLowerCase().split(';',1)[0].trim();

    var mimeTypes = [
      'application/zip'
    ];
    
    return (mimeTypes.indexOf(headerValue) !== -1);
  }
}

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method !== 'GET') {
      return;
    }
    
    if (!isAllowed(details)) {
      return;
    }

    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({
      addRules: [{
        'id': 2001,
        'priority': 1,
        'action': {
          'type': 'redirect',
          'redirect': {
            url: chrome.runtime.getURL('web/main.html')
         }
        },
        'condition': {
          'urlFilter': details.url,
          'resourceTypes': ['main_frame']
        }
      }],
    removeRuleIds: [2001]
    });
  
    return { redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('web/main.html') };
  },
  {
    urls: [
      '<all_urls>'
    ],
    types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame']
  },
  ['responseHeaders']
 );
```

[***Full source for mv3***](https://bitbucket.org/jan_popov/mv3/src/master/)

For extension with mv3, above code achieved similar action as code for mv2.
The difference is that: when I click on anchor that pointed to zip file, then on the first click the dialog "save as" is shown and if I click on same zip anchor for second time, then redirect occurs.
For other zip files above actions are repeated.

How I can modify mv3 code to achieve same results as mv2?

Comment: ManifestV3 removed webRequest's ability to modify the requests so your `redirectUrl` is ignored. There's no solution via API currently until https://crbug.com/1141166 is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

This is still possible, but requires abandoning the `chrome.webRequest` API in favor of [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/). This allows your extension talk to the [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) protocol, where you can hook into the request/response lifecycle.

The first step is to attach the debugger the `tabId` in question, and send enable commands (if required) for the APIs you are using. [Here](https://grep.app/search?q=chrome.debugger.attach) you can find many examples of how to do this. For example, let's assume we want to use `Fetch`, so we need to send [Fetch.enable](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-enable).

Now, if you want to modify a request/response before it is processed, on a high level you need to:

- Set up a handler for [Fetch.requestPaused](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#event-requestPaused), configuring your target URL patterns (or `*` for all).
- Check the request stage as described in the doc.
- If **Request**: modify headers, and send [Fetch.continueRequest](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-continueRequest).
- If **Response**: Get the response body by sending [Fetch.getResponseBody](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-getResponseBody). If desired, modify body/status/headers. Fulfill the response to client by sending [Fetch.fulfillRequest](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-getResponseBody).

Helpful:

- https://grep.app/search?q=chrome.debugger.sendCommand
- https://grep.app/search?q=Fetch.fulfillRequest

I am using this approach successfully in a chrome extension project. MV3 killed the native extension request API (or at least, severely limited it) so for now this is the only option I am aware of. The downside is, an annoying bar appears under the tab, saying this browser is currently being debugged by $EXT_NAME.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent closing that "this browser is currently being debugged by $EXT_NAME" bar? I'm developing an enterprise security extension to prevent navigation to certain websites and attach specific headers to all requests, end users should not be able to turn it off. Thanks.